How to combine nth-child and hover in TailwindCSS?
Is it possible to combine nth-child and hover in tailwind?
<tr key={i} className='[&>*:nth-child(even)]:bg-[white] hover:bg-[#6b7280] [&>*:nth-child(odd)]:bg-[#eee] hover:bg-[#6b7280]'>

This is what i currently have, but now hover does not work, without the even rule, only the odd columns get changed on hover ...
EDIT: new version of the code:
{dataProtokoll.map((k, i) => {
  return (
    <tr key={i} className='[&>*:nth-child(odd)]:bg-[#eee] [&>*:nth-child(even)]:bg-[white] group' onClick={() => { i === selectedRowProtokoll ? setSelectedRowProtokoll(-1) : setSelectedRowProtokoll(i) }}>
      <>
        {Object.values(k).map(value => <td className={clsx('text-left border px-2.5 py-2 border-solid border-[rgb(160_160_160)] group-hover:bg-[#6b7280]', { 'bg-[#6b7280]': i === selectedRowProtokoll })}>{value}</td>)}
      </>
    </tr>
  );
})}


Just use these class prefixes: first:, second:, odd:, even:, last:. You can use it in every child class. No matter the index, they will be applied to the specific div.

You are applying background-color to the <tr> on hover. The inner elements (presumably <td> elements) have their own background colors. The <td> elements' background colors draw over the <tr> element's background color, so it is never shown. Instead, you could consider changing the background colors of all the <td> elements like:


function App() {
  const i = 0;
  const items = Array(10).fill(null);

  return (
    <table>
      <tr key={i} className='[&>*:nth-child(even)]:bg-[white] [&>*:nth-child(odd)]:bg-[#eee] *:hover:!bg-[#6b7280]'>
        {items.map((_, i) => (
          <td>Cell {i}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



Or:


function App() {
  const i = 0;
  const items = Array(10).fill(null);

  return (
    <table>
      <tr key={i} className='[&>*:nth-child(even)]:bg-[white] [&>*:nth-child(odd)]:bg-[#eee] group'>
        {items.map((_, i) => (
          <td class="group-hover:bg-[#6b7280]">Cell {i}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>




Interestingly enough, now only every second column gets turned dark-grey, instead of all, ill edit my question for the new version of the code!

Seems to work fine in this JSFiddle. Consider providing an actual reproduction of the problem, rather than just the code itself.

Sry, i worked, i had two instances of the table in different files, i updated the wrong table. The second one worked for me(atleast thats the solution i tried.)
